# CSS: How to put content between header and footer

Tags: html, css

I want to do a page with **3 sections**:

- **Header** (top of the page)
- **Footer** (bottom of the page)
- **Content** - Between header and footer without scrollbar (is a leaflet map). The content starts just in the end of header and ends in the start of footer.

At this moment I have `position:fixed` the header and the footer.

What CSS rules I need to add in the content to adjust between this 2 sections?

My problem is that If I adjust the content height in pixels is not working in every screen, only in mine.

[image: sections]

```css
header,
footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
}
footer {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
}
section {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px; /*But this is not working in all screens! */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try using vh units http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: I added an example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in this example I use 30px for the header and 30px for the footer.
Use this code:

```
section {
   height: calc(100vh - 60px);
   top: 30px;
}
```

It calculates 100vw (viewport height, similar to percent) minus 60px (30px for the header, 30 for the footer) and then it's position is right under the header.

I hope this works for you.